# Convert Certificate to X.509

Tags: ssl, import, certificate, x509

Good morning,

I recently requested a certificate from GoDaddy and they have sent me two sets of .pem and .spc files (SHA1 and SHA1) but when I try to import them to my codesignstore it says they are not X.509. Is there any way to convert them?

I used these commands to generate the files that I sent to GoDaddy.

Keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias codesigncert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=Corp,O=Corp,C=US,ST=FL,L=Orlando" -keystore codesignstore
```

Certificate Request

```
keytool -certreq -v -alias codesigncert -file codesign.pem -keystore codesignstore
```

Import

```
keytool –import –alias codesignecert –file NAME_OF_FILE_FROM_GODADDY –keystore codesignstore
```

Comment: can you provide more information, regarding the files received from godaddy? You should have received a bundle.crt, and crt , is this correct? Also, can you check which format they are, by opening the files and checking if they start with "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried importing a trustcert using the below command and it worked for me.

> keytool.exe -import  -trustcacerts -alias "cert_alias_name" -file cert.pem  -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_291/lib/security/cacerts" -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -v -noprompt
> Certificate was added to keystore
> [Storing C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_291/lib/security/cacerts]